# Mac CI through terminal, can’t download xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, continuous-integration

I rented a dedicated macOS 64 but arm machine on AWS. I can’t have GUI access to this machine. How can I install Xcode on terminal and use xcodebuild? I tried xcinfo, it failed to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to install Xcode

On your local machine:

1. Install cookies.txt Chrome extension
2. Login to Apple Developer site and get the url for downloading
3. Run cookies.txt extension and download cookies.txt file

On CI machine:

4. curl --cookie cookies.txt -O
5. xip -x Xcode.xip
6. sudo xcode-select -r
7. sudo xcode-select -p
8. sudo xcodebuild -license accept
9. sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch

Or, use https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes